# Mobile Application design: Menu Driven vs Tab Control

Tags: iphone, android

iPhone does not have Menus AFAIK; most of the stuff is driven by on screen controls and widgets. 
Android has menus, ofcourse. I am working on porting an iPhone application on Android platform.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of the Menu driven approach?

Answer (score 4):

I would think that the TabBar driven app in the iPhone OS is very similar to a Menu Driven app under Android.  While visually they are slightly different, they could be worked to do similar things.

Of course the advantage of using the OS Common UI elements is HUGE.  If you port an iPhone to Android without really considering how the UI elements translate, you end up with a sloppy port.  The same is true if you go from Android to iPhone.

Step back and look at the functionality you are trying to create.  Read the iPhone HIG.  Read the Android Developers Guide.  Layout your app specifically for each.  With good MVC, the design of the data model will be almost 100% the same.  The Views may be way different but similar (if that makes sense) and controllers will have many methods in common but slightly different logic underneath them.